# ZMQ SUB/PUB C++ code example without signals/mutex/,,,

Tags: multithreading, zeromq

I have recently met with ZMQ and find it very usefull for my C/C++ networking projects. However, I cannot get rid of standard multithread methods like mutex/signals, etc... in my mindset. I saw some simple examples on how to sync things inproc zmq but I fail to figure out more complicated way.
Could somebody draw me a concept of achieving the following with zmq paterns. C/C++ module should have the following:

1. be able to publish data to given port/address
2. be able to subscribe to given port/address and receive data (start NewDataAvailable callback when new data is in)
3. be able to change sub/pub port and address during runtime

Methods from 1,2,3 can be called from different threads in my process and currently I have one ugly mutex at all zmq calls to make zmq thinks it's in single thread. It works but I don't like it so any example or link is welcomed.

Thanks!